# Tags for contact in drupal view shown on separate rows

Tags: drupal-views, tags

I'm creating a drupal view based on civicontact.  The fields are user id, user roles, I link to civicrm_uf_match table to get the contact id, then add a field for the tags associated with that contact.  The problem is that each tag is shown on a separate row.  This does not happen with user roles, the are shown as a single comma delimited text field, which is what I wanted to have happen with the civiCRM tags.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [views_merge_rows](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_merge_rows) module to render the Tags in to a comma separated list